# Position of image <input> open dialog on Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, mobile-safari

I need to trigger browser image selection from photo library/camera in response to user clicking a custom element (hiding the default `<input>`).

Using the standard code often suggested for this.

The HTML:

```
<input id="image-input" style="display: none" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
<button onclick="browse()">BROWSE</button>
```

And script:

```
<script>
  function browse() {
    document.getElementById("image-input").click();
  }
</script>
```

This works as expected but on iOS (iPhone, 15.4), the position of the popup dialog is unpredictable.

Most of the time the dialog pops up under the button but not exactly at the same place, and sometimes it just pops up at the bottom of the page. I can't seem to determine what user action causes the different behaviors.

[image]

If I remember correctly, in previous iOS versions this dialog would open as a fixed drawer at the bottom of the screen?

Is there any way to control the position of this dialog? Ideally, I'd like it to just open as a fixed modal drawer at the bottom but anything that can make a consistent controllable behavior would work too.

Comment: Have you tried to call `focus()` on the input prior to calling click?

Comment: Could you create a runnable demo with the problem that we can test? I tried myself but could not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VincentOrback There isn't much else on the page besides the html basics. Just the hidden <input>, the button and the script.

Comment: I've found that I can get the menu to appear in odd locations even when I'm not using javascript to simulate a click on the input, but actually tapping it with my finger.

Answer (score 2):

So I took a look at this issue on my iPhone 8+, Safari, iOS 15.2.1

`I created this fiddle here to play around with:` https://codepen.io/treckstar_/pen/oNELeqY

I couldn't replicate the exact issue you are saying. What I got was the opposite. I unhid the file input so I could try clicking both of them and see what happens. Every few times I would click the "should be hidden" input, the file open dialog would open at the top where the browse button is.

Since we don't have the exact code, I can't be positive, but I am thinking that whatever hidden input you have is located somewhere at the bottom of the page and its just showing up where the last input was clicked was at.

I think the main issue is using JavaScript/jQuery to click a button causes intermittent positioning of the dialog box for file inputs on iOS Safari.

So I would recommend my solution to be, not use JavaScript/jQuery to click the file button.

You could potentially setup a button with the file upload positions over top of it, and with opacity set to 0.

```css
#image-input {
  position: absolute !important;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  clip: rect(0px, 40px, 40px, 0px);
  opacity: 0.0;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<a id="image-file-button" data-role="button">Button</a>
<input id="image-input" type="file" data-role="none" name="image-file-upload" />
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create this. I can reproduce the behavior I described with this code on iPhone X and iOS 15.4.1. Clicking on the button, the dialog opens in slightly different positions near it and once in a long while, it appears at the bottom of the page (like in my screenshot). It does seem to be related to invoking the click event manually in JS.

I was hoping there's some way to have more control over this dialog's position, this was the main intent of my question. I wanted to avoid using transparent inputs but if there's no other option, I may have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue occurs to my iphone x. I think it's safari browser's default issue (can't say if it's issue or feature) but what I've experienced is that it dispalys the file input dialog according to our **TAP POSITION**. You can see this in the video here.

Click to See the Video

[image: 1]

Comment: Where does the input dialog display when you tap the button at its lowest extremity?  There has to be a work-around for this

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the popup moving could be that another element on the page is moving it and changing where it moves to, on different devices it will be in different places because it is moved to where it won't look smashed.

Comment: Not sure I understand the answer. Why would another element move it? I don't have other elements on the page, it's just a a hidden <input> and the button.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `input.click()` action inside a `setTimeout`. 50 millisec should do the trick

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).